# Утечка памяти в односвязном линейном списке

Tags: c++, указатели, утечка-памяти, односвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Требуется написать односвязный линейный список с возможностью удалять и добавлять узлы с обоих концов списка, а также функцию, которая удаляла бы список полностью. Я написал для этого программу, которая представленная ниже. Проблема в том, что я не уверен что метод destroy(), который должен уничтожать список, полностью освобождает память, которая была выделена под список. Для проверки программы на утечки памяти, я создал цикл с большим числом итераций внутри которого создается и уничтожается список. Программа крашится. В диспетчере задач, график потребления памяти в промежутке между запуском и крашем программы, похож на график при утечке памяти. В чем ошибка и как её исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
struct SinglyLinkedListNode
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
    int data;
};
struct SinglyLinkedListStruct
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode* head;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* tail;
    void push_back(int val)
    {

        SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode;
        currNode->data = val;
        currNode->next = NULL;
        if (tail == NULL)
        {
            head = currNode;
            tail = currNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = currNode;
            tail = currNode;
        }
    }
    void push_front(int val)
    {
        SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode;
        currNode->data = val;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            currNode->next = NULL;
            head = currNode;
            tail = currNode;
        }
        else
        {
            currNode->next = head;
            head = currNode;
        }
    }
    int pop_back()
    {
        if (!tail)
            return NULL;
        SinglyLinkedListNode* prevTail = NULL;
        for (SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = head; currNode != tail; currNode = currNode->next)
            prevTail = currNode;
        int popedValue = tail->data;
        delete tail;
        prevTail->next = NULL;
        tail = prevTail;
        return popedValue;
    }
    int pop_front()
    {
        if (!head)
            return NULL;
        SinglyLinkedListNode* nextHead = head->next;
        int popedValue = head->data;
        delete head;
        head = nextHead;
        return popedValue;
    }
    void destroy()
    {
        for (SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = head, *nodeToDestroy = NULL; currNode; nodeToDestroy = currNode, currNode = currNode->next)
            if (nodeToDestroy)
                delete nodeToDestroy;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
};
int main()
{

    SinglyLinkedListStruct slList{ NULL, NULL };
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 4000000000; i++) 
    {
        slList.push_back(5);
        slList.push_back(6);

        slList.push_front(4);
        slList.push_front(3);

        slList.push_back(7);

        slList.push_front(2);

        slList.push_back(8);

        slList.push_front(1);

        slList.destroy();

    }

    for (SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = slList.head; currNode; currNode = currNode->next)
        std::cout << currNode->data << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверять на утечки памяти через диспетчер задач не самая удачная идея. Воспользуйтесь специализированными инструментами: `valgrind`, `leak sanitizer` и др. Ну а ошибка у вас, скорее всего, потому что вы обращаетесь по невалидному адресу. Тобишь смотрите использование неинициализированных указателей и использование указателей после освобождения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `destroy` последнюю `nodeToDestroy` **не** удаляете. После `for` надо `delete nodeToDestroy;`. Или попроще так :

```
void destroy()
    {  SinglyLinkedListNode*nex;
       for (SinglyLinkedListNode* currNode = head; currNode;
          currNode = nex) {
          nex = currNode->next ;
          delete currNode ; }
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
```